# Month Picker from react-datepicker doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using `react-datepicker` node module to pick month-year . But It is showing dates as well . I dont want to show date picker . Im including link of the documents I'm following to do so . Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Here is the code

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
      showMonthYearPicker
    />
  );
};
```

[react-datepicker node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker)

[examples of react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

Comment: Please include your code and what you have tried so far to fix the issue.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi added code snippet , please check

Comment: I tried your code in the https://reactdatepicker.com/ playground and it worked just fine, are you maybe using an old version of Datepicker?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yeah , with latest version it is working fine , Thanks